# LTspice parameter sweep and sampling

Tags: ltspice, parameters

**Setup**

I am trying to run a parameter sweep in LTspice in order to generate STDP curves for a memristor.

I'm doing this by sweeping a time-delta parameter `dT` between -50 and +50 ms, in order to run 100 transient analyses with the "post-synaptic" voltage source shifted w.r.t. to the "pre-synaptic" at each one.
[image]

```
.param dT=-50m
.step param dT -50m 50m 1m
```

The pulse that is seen around 200 ms is to read the current through one of the probes of the device I'm measuring.

**The problem**

I would like to sample each of the simulations by taking the current at one of the electrodes of my device at 206 ms, in order to compile them into a classical STDP graph with dT as x-axis and current as y-axis.
[image]

**Solution:**

`.meas res find ix(u1:te) at 206m` did the trick to be able to measure the current through the device.
I was then able to plot my quantity of interest by View > Spice Error Log > Right click on res > Plot step'ed .meas data .
[image]

Comment: I haven't read what you wrote well enough to feel I understand all of it. But have you looked at the .MEAS card, yet?

Comment: I have and I was thinking of using `.MEAS <probe> AT 206m`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @ThomasTiotto You're on the right track, but you'll have to use something in the lines of `.meas <probe> find <quantity> at 206m`, where `<quantity>` can be either `time` or any signal or math with signals (i.e. `v(out)**2`). Then open up the error log, RClick and select *plot step'ped data* (or similar).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen `.meas <probe> find <quantity> at 206m` did the trick.  I was then able to plot my quantity of interest by View > Spice Error Log > Plot step'ed .meas data

Comment: @ThomasTiotto If you omit `find <quantity>` and just write `.meas <name> when <condition>`, it is implied that it's using `.meas <name> find time when <condition>`. That's why `<quantity>` explicitly uses `<quantity>` for finding.

Comment: Please post your "solution" section as an *answer* instead of appending it to your *question* post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

`.meas res find ix(u1:te) at 206m` did the trick to be able to measure the current through the device.
I was then able to plot my quantity of interest by `View > Spice Error Log > Right click on res > Plot step'ed .meas data` .
[image]

Comment: You can accept your own answer, too. It will let future people know, when searching for similar problems, that this problem has an accepted solution.